# Making a radiobutton selection required

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I have radio buttons within a `datagrid` which is within a `repeater`. There are 4 `radiobuttons` that are created for each "repeat" within the `repeater` and I want to make the selection of 1 of these 4 mandatory. I have already put these `radiobuttons` within the same `GroupName`, so only 1 of them can be selected.

They are not in a radiobuttonlist and I do not want to place it in a radiobutton list.

Comment: This can be done in any number of ways, either through validators or simply checking to see if a radio button selection has been made. What have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, I know validators do exist, but I do not know how to validate them toeether because they are not the same control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have them in the same group name you can make a custom validator.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="myValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="you must select one" onservervalidate="myValidator_serverValidate" />
```

Then in the code behind,

```
   protected void myValidator_serverValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e) 
    { 
      bool isSelected = false; 

      foreach (Control control in yourForm.Controls) 
      { 
         if (control == RadioButton) 
         { 
         RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)control; 
         if (rb.GroupName == "myGroup" && rb.Checked) 
         { 
           isSelected = true; 
         } 
         } 
      } 
       e.IsValid = isSelected; 
    }
```